# What is the Optimized way to Paginate Active Record Objects with Filter?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to display the Users list in pagination with my rails API, However I have few constraints here before displaying the users I want to check users who have access to the view files, Here is the code:

```
  def verified_client
    conditions = {}
    conditions[:user_name] = fetch_verified_users_with_api_call # returns[user_1,user_2, ....]
    @users = User.where(conditions).where('access NOT LIKE ?', 'admin_%').ordered
    will_paginate(@users, params[:page])
  end
```

Q1) Is there a way where I don't have to make sql call when users try to fetch subsequent pages(page 2, page 3.. page n)?

Q2) What would happen when verified_users list return million on items? I suspect the SQL will fail

I could have used limit and offset with the Query, but I will not know the total result and page size to achieve the same I have to fire one more SQL call to get count and write up own logic to get number of pages.

Generated SQL:

```
select  *
    from  users
    where  user_name IN (user_1, user_2 .... user_10000)
      AND  (access NOT LIKE 'admin_%')
```

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.

Comment: select * from users where user_name IN (user_1, user_2 .... user_10000) AND (access NOT LIKE 'admin_%')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That query is hard to optimize.  It probably does essentially all the work for each page and there is no good way to prevent this scan.  Adding these may help:

```
INDEX(access)
INDEX(user, access)
```

I have seen 70K items in an IN list, but I have not heard of 1M.  What is going on?  Would it be shorter to say which users are *not* included?  Could there be another table with the user list?  (Sometimes a `JOIN` works better than IN, especially if you have already run a Select to get the list.)

Could the admins be filtered out of the IN list *before* building this query?  Then,

```
INDEX(user)
```

is likely to be quite beneficial.

Is there at most one row per user?  If so, then pagination can be revised to be *very* efficient.  This is done by "remembering where you left off" instead of using `OFFSET`.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Answer (score 2):

> Q1) Is there a way where I don't have to make sql call when users try
> to fetch subsequent pages(page 2, page 3.. page n)?

The whole idea of pagination is that you make the query faster by returning a small subset of the total number of records. In most cases the number of  requests for the first page will vastly outnumber the other pages so this could very well be a case of premature optimization that might do more harm then good.

If is actually a problem its better adressed with SQL caching, ETags or other caching mechanisms - not by loading a bunch of pages at once.

> Q2) What would happen when verified_users list return million on items? I suspect the SQL will fail

Your database or application will very likely slow to a halt and then crash when it runs out of memory. Exactly what happens depends on your architecture and how grumpy your boss is on that given day.

Comment: Is there a optimized solution for the above problem ?

Comment: That just begs the question "optimized for what?" which you haven't defined. I would worry less and solve the optimization if and when its actually a problem and you know what you're actually optimizing for.

Comment: Rephrasing the Question: What should be the design approach to solve both Question 1 & Question 2

Comment: There is no single design approach to solve them. Optimization without a clear goal is inself an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1) Is there a way where I don't have to make sql call when users try to fetch subsequent pages(page 2, page 3.. page n)?

You can get the whole result set and store it in your app.  As far as the database is concerned this is not slow or non-optimal.  Then performance including memory is your app's problem.

> Q2) What would happen when verified_users list return million on items? I suspect the SQL will fail

What will happen is all those entries will be concatenated in the SQL string.  There is likely a maximum SQL string size and a million entries would be too much.

A possible solution is if you have a way to identify the verified users in the database and do a join with that table.

> What is the Optimized way to Paginate Active Record Objects with Filter?

The three things which are not premature optimizations with databases is (1) use indexed queries not table scans, (2) avoid correlated sub-queries, and (3) reduce network turns.

Make sure you have an index it can use, in particular for the order.  So make sure you know what order you are asking for.

If instead of the `access` field starting with a prefix if you had a field to indicate an admin user you can make an index with the first field as that admin field and the second field as what you are ordering by.  This allows the database to sort the records efficiently, especially important when paging with `offset` and `limit`.

As for network turns you might want to use paging and not worry about network turns.  One idea is to prefetch the next page if possible.  So after it gets the results of page 1, query for page 2.  Hold the page 2 results until viewed, but when viewed then get the results for page 3.